# VB.NET Returning an Object

Tags: vb.net

Will the following statement cause a memory leak:

```
Imports System.Data.SQLClient

Public Function getConnection () As SQLConnection
    return New SQLConnection()
End Function

Public Sub TestConnection()
    Dim con As SQLConnection
    con = getConnection
    con.close
    con = Nothing
End Sub
```

How does .close or .dispose get called on the SQLConnection in getConnection?

Comment: Why do you need `getConnection`? Why dont you simply create a new instance inside `TestConnection`?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, I have added an Imports statement to make it clear.

Comment: @igrimpe, the getConnection() function is required because the function could return an Oracle connection.  I added the simple code above just to explain the question.

Comment: @w0051977, `Oracle` Connection or `Sql` Connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no memory leak because it will be garbage collected after you've called the method.

But this method does nothing but causing confusion. You should always dispose connections(which closes it implicitely) as soon as you're finished with it (even in case of an exception).

You can do that in a finally of a `Try/Finally` or (easier) with the [`Using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement. But since both approaches need to wrap the connection, your method enables the calling method to forget it. Therefore it is bad practise.

So simply do this:

```
Public Sub TestConnection()
    Using con = New SqlConnection("connection string here")
        Using cmd = new SqlCommand("sql query here", con)
            ' do something, f.e. cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() '
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. TestConnection is structured as you stated. Perhaps I should have included it (I didn't think it was relevant to the question). Could you explain, which method: "does nothing but causing confusion".

Comment: @w0051977: Your `getConnection` since it does not add anything.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a reference type, hence you operate on the same instance in TestConnection so no memory leak here.
At the end you have 2 instances with null (gc will collect them), but the connection is closed.

Comment: Are you sure it is returning a reference type? The 'New' keyword is used.

Comment: Of course! It's a class. You instantiate classes with the new keyword.

Comment: Thanks.  Objects live on the heap.  That is what I was confused about.